# Reference custom params file in dvc template / dict unpacking

Tags: dvc

The examples for [template referencing](https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/project-structure/dvcyaml-files#templating) and [dict unpacking](https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/project-structure/dvcyaml-files#dictionary-unpacking) assume the default `params.yaml` file.

So if for example I have the following `params.yaml`

```
group:
  param_one: some_value
```

We can do

1. Template: `python script.py --param_one ${group.param_one}`
2. Dict: `python script.py ${group}`

But how do I reference a custom params file?

```
  params:
    - config/my_params.json:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the top-level [`vars`](https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/project-structure/dvcyaml-files#variables) of `dvc.yaml`:

Given `config/my_params.json`:

```json
{"group": {"foo": 1, "bar": 2}}
```

Your `dvc.yaml` would look like:

```yaml
vars:
  - config/my_params.json

stages:
  echo-group:
    cmd: echo ${group}
```

Resulting in:

```
$ dvc repro
Running stage 'echo-group':                                                  
> echo --foo 1 --bar 2
--foo 1 --bar 2
Generating lock file 'dvc.lock'                                       
Updating lock file 'dvc.lock'
```